# Different number of bit for the ADC and DAC linked to a \$\mu\$controller - Electrochemical sensor

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, adc, dac, education

I am studying an electrochemical sensor (see figures below please) where the number of the bit of the DAC ([Analog Devices AD5685R](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5686R_5685R_5684R.pdf)) is 14, whereas the number of the bit of the ADC ([Analog Devices AD7682](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7682_7689.pdf)) is 16. The \$\mu\$controller ([Microchip dsPIC33EP256MC204](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70000657H.pdf)) can handle 16 bit data.

[image]

The potentiostat is the following:

[image]

Why did the designer choose a 14 bit DAC, instead of a 16 bit DAC?

---

I took the above sensor from [a paper](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07984214833506389383); in it there should be the necessary information to understand the reason of the choice, but I do not find it.

Comment: Who knows - maybe it fulfilled project requirements about accuracy and cost but we don't know what the project requirements were.

Comment: Hello @Justme, I took the above sensor from a paper (see edit above).

Comment: Cost, familiarity, availability, or some other specification characteristic.  Why not choose the 14-bit DAC if that is enough?

Comment: Hello @kkrambo, I was thinking that if the cost is important, the designer should have to choose a 14 bit ADC as well because it is cheaper.